# Drag an event in fullCalendar component with a specific duration

Tags: drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I've seen the solution to [drag and drop external events in fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/external-dragging.html). But, in this demo, all the external events have a duration of 2 hours (because defaultEventMinutes parameter is set to 120). I'm trying to change this demo in order to manage events with different durations. Say, "My event 1" is 45min long, "My event 2" is 165min, etc.

At the beginning I though there may be an attribute to store the duration in the eventObject, but according to the documentation, it's not the case.
Then, I thought it would be possible to change the value of 'defaultEventMinutes' when starting dragging the event. But apparently, I can't do it without rebuilding the whole calendar.

According to you, what is the best means to meet this requirement?
Thanks in advance for your advice...

Comment: https://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/external-dragging.html/ no longer works... :(

Answer (score 3):

Worked on this as well and have solved the duration shown on fullCalendar this way:

1. Having a custom "setOptions" function for fullCalendar.
2. Having a property for fullCalendar called "dragMinutes" that can be set during elements $(this).draggable({start:...}).

Here is the code for the custom setOptions:

```
 ...
    function Calendar(element, options, eventSources) {
        var t = this;

        // hack for setting options that updates
        function setOptions(new_options, refresh) {
            $.extend(options, new_options);
            if (refresh) {
                var viewName = currentView.name;
                changeView(viewName, true);
            }
        }
    // exports ... 
    t.setOptions = setOptions;
    ...
```

Heres the code for handling "dragMinutes" option in fullCalendar:

```
/* External Dragging
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


function dragStart(_dragElement, ev, ui) {
    hoverListener.start(function (cell) {
        clearOverlays();
        if (cell) {
            if (cellIsAllDay(cell)) {
                renderCellOverlay(cell.row, cell.col, cell.row, cell.col);
            } else {
                var d1 = cellDate(cell);
                if (opt('dragMinutes'))
                    var d2 = addMinutes(cloneDate(d1), opt('dragMinutes'));
                else
                    var d2 = addMinutes(cloneDate(d1), opt('defaultEventMinutes'));
                renderSlotOverlay(d1, d2);
            }
        }
    }, ev);
}
```

And heres how i make event draggable and update the "dragMinutes":

```
    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        containment: 'document',
        // return a custom styled elemnt being dragged
        helper: function (event) {
            return $('<div class="uv-planning-dragging"></div>').html($(this).html());
        },
        opacity: 0.70,
        zIndex: 10000,
        appendTo: 'body',
        cursor: 'move',
        revertDuration: 0,
        revert: true, 
        start: function (e, ui) {
            // set the "dragMinutes" option in fullCalendar so shown interval about to be added is correct.
            var data = $(this).data('eventObject');
            if (data) {
                var min = data.jsonProps.durationMsec / 1000 / 60;
                if (macroCalendar.calendar) {
                    macroCalendar.calendar.fullCalendar('setOptions', { dragMinutes: Math.round(min) }, false);
                }
            }
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            // further process

        }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey @mrw, I am trying to achieve this but I think your code is for older version, do have the updated one. Fullcalendar 2.2 or so! would be of great help. thnx

Answer (score 3):

If anyone still visits the thread and don't find the solution, the solution would be to set the duration parameter in event div... and then call draggable on that div.

```
$(this).data('event', {
    title: 'new event title', // use the element's text as the event title
    id: $(this).attr('id'),
    stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    duration: '03:00:00' // will set the duration during drag of event
});
```

Comment: Great Answer, 2021 and finally found the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the best solution I have found is adding a *duration* attribute on my event Object, then the code to create my fullCalendar looks like this:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            // HERE I force the end date based on the start date + duration
            copiedEventObject.end = new Date(date.getTime() + copiedEventObject.duration * 60 * 1000);
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }

        }
    });
```

The only drawback is when you're dragging the event, the event duration looks like *defaultEventMinutes* and not the actual duration, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

These special properties can either be specified in the provided event object, or they can be standalone data attributes:

```
<!-- DURATION OF 3 hours EVENT WILL PROPAGATE TO CALENDAR WHEN DROPPED -->
<div class='draggable' data-event='1' data-duration='03:00' />
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/eventReceive/

Answer (score 0):

With the latest `fullcalendar v2.0.2`, if you want the overlay to be of the particular duration, you can update in this function of `fullcalendar-arshaw.js`

```
function dragStart(_dragElement, ev, ui) {
    hoverListener.start(function(cell) {
        clearOverlays();
        if (cell) {
            var seconds = duration_in_minutes * 1000 * 60 ;
           // we need to pass seconds into milli-seconds
            if (d1.hasTime()) {                 
                d2.add(seconds);
                renderSlotOverlay(d1, d2, cell.col);
            }
            else {
                d2.add(calendar.defaultAllDayEventDuration);
                renderDayOverlay(d1, d2, true, cell.col);
            }
        }
    }, ev);
}
```

Here, pass your duration in the external events object and that object you can fetch in `_dragElement` and then convert it into milli-seconds and pass it in `d2.add(seconds)`. This will create the shadow of that mili-seconds on that calendar.

Answer (score 0):

For non-external events you can use the fullcalendar settings:

```
defaultTimedEventDuration: (hours+':00:00'),
forceEventDuration: true,
// defaultEventMinutes: hours*60, // not needed
```

and in the event data you do not set the end property (or you null it):

```
eventData = {
    title: title,
    start: start,
    // end: end, // MUST HAVE no end for fixedduration
    color: '#00AA00',
    editable: true, // for dragging
};
```

Ref: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultTimedEventDuration/

Tip: In case you want to prevent the resizing of the events which is possible due to `editable: true`, you can use CSS to hide the handle: `.fc-resizer.fc-end-resizer { display:none; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since v4 some of the above options are not working at all. The problem i was facing was as follows:

All day items for me have a duration, but not a start time. When i select a start time by dragging, the start time is set but as soon as i set the end date ( which is done similar as above answers ), the end date is reset again.. there is something buggy going on in the setDate function... the end date is set, this part works, then it does a comparisson on itself to find out the time difference between the dates, but the date is already set by the system itself causing the difference to be 0 which is causing the enddate to be set to null again......

A giant pain in my neck i got to say... it works perfect when staying within the timeline, but that's about it.

I managed to 'fix', more like destroy it by using this line in the eventDrop event, but it will also work in any other events you may use:

- update your event with ajax here, since you have the start and end date *
- calendar.refetchEvents(); in the success function

This is going to refetch all the events, it sounds pretty killer for performance but it doesn't seem to take up much time, try it for yourself.
This way my titles, times etc are always up to date and the calendar is showing the right end date.